# Where to get a tutorial on how to create full 3d panoramic cube images set with your camera and photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, tutorial, panorama

So on adobetv I  found tuts on simple one image panorama creation like [this](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/photoshop-cs4-sneak-peek/enhanced-panoramic-photomerge/) but I want to know how esely create panoramas like for [such artworks](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/geometry_panorama.html) (there were used images

('http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/textures/cube/skybox/px.jpg'), // right
            ('http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/textures/cube/skybox/nx.jpg'), // left
            ('http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/textures/cube/skybox/py.jpg'), // top
            ('http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/textures/cube/skybox/ny.jpg'), // bottom
            ('http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/textures/cube/skybox/pz.jpg'), // back
            ('http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/textures/cube/skybox/nz.jpg') // fron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be split into two tasks, 1) making a 360 panorama and 2) using software to rotate the panorama around a central "view".  In the link you provided the 2nd part is being handled by JavaScript from the three.js project.  Making images to work with three.js would require making a "flat" panorama first and cutting it into the right pieces.
It's probably easier to just use software to do the whole thing.  This tutorial should help:  http://matadornetwork.com/bnt/2006/11/26/what-is-a-360-degree-panoramic-photo-and-how-to-make-one/

Comment: Any way of doing it in photoshop?

Comment: You can make the panorama in Photoshop, but not the 3d rotation part; that needs software to display as there isn't any standard format like JPG for 3D panoramas.  Here's how to use Photoshop to make a 2D panorama: http://www.digital-photography-school.com/creating-a-panorama-with-photoshop-and-photomerge

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial:
[How to make your own SkyBox with a digital camera](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~tvs/skybox/)

Skymaps/cubes for CGI use are a different beast from simple photomerge panos created from a handful of images, or a 360-degree cylindrical pano. What you need to do is cover the entire spherical view, and then create the six cube face mappings for a skybox format.  A blender tutorial on doing this from a mirrorball image can be found here:

[Blender 3D: Noob to Pro/Build a skybox](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Build_a_skybox)

If you want to create a skybox with photography, then you'll have to shoot enough images to cover the entire sphere (with a typical ultrawide rectilinear lens, that'll be something like 20+ images: typically three rows in portrait format, with zenith and nadir shots.  And will be difficult to accomplish without a specialized panohead to rotate the lens around its no-parallax point to stitch cleanly.

Photoshop's photomerge function cannot handle this type of panorama easily. I'd suggest the open source [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net) stitcher, which can create equirectangular 360x180 panos.  Then you'd need to remap it to the cube faces, either with a Hugin CLI script, or a GUI tool like [Pano2VR](http://ggnome.com/pano2vr).

However, make sure that you need to do this. Packages like [Blender can directly use equirectangulars or mirrorball/lightprobe images for environment maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5681/add-a-panoramic-background-to-scene-in-cycles) if you use the Cycles renderer, so the skybox mapping may not be required.

See also: [How are virtual tour photos taken?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8129/how-are-virtual-tour-photos-taken)